# When the async functions comes to lock, what happens? C# Lock

Tags: c#, asynchronous, locking

I was wondering what happens when this function is called by async functions.

```
public void Method(ClassA myObject)
{
   ClassB converted = Convert.ChangeType(myObject, typeof(ClassB));
   if(!converted) return;

   lock(currentObject)
   {
      if(!currentObject) currentObject = converted;
      else myQueue.Enqueue(converted);
   }

   // change some variables of ‘converted’
}
```

What I am doing is that I check if the parameter is inherited by a specific class. If not, no need to execute the rest of the code. If so, I lock the ‘currentObject’ variable. If currentObject is null then I assign the converted variable. If not, I add the variable to the queque to change currentObject variable later. Lastly, I modify some variables of the converted object.

Let’s say this function is called simultaneously by 2 functions. The first one will lock the variable and will do its job. What does the second one do in this scenario?

Does it execute the code until the lock statement and wait for the first one to finish and then continue to execute the function? Does it ignore the lock statement and continue to change some variables and finish the function? Does it ignore the function completely?

What I want is that I want the second one to be added in the queue since the currentObject is not null anymore.

Comment: The lock block 2nd process from continuing.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn’t understand. Does the 2nd process add the variable in the queue? Does it work like what I want?

Comment: @jdweng You mean thread. Threads and processes are two different things. Thread is on application level and process is OS level.

Comment: This is unlikely to be correct code.  At least one intention is to keep the queue thread-safe, so only one thread at a time can call Enqueue().  The same locking object must be used in the Dequeue() call.  The lock on currentObject cannot provide that guarantee, since there is no guarantee that the object it references is the same object.  The universal advice about `lock` applies here as well, you *must* create a dedicated object to store the lock state.

Comment: @Hans Passant I am new in this subject and I am trying to understand what does the second one do in this case. Do I have to add the queue in the lock statement as well? I just add a new variable to the queue. Sorry, if it is a dumb question.

Comment: `Does it execute the code until the lock statement and wait for the first one to finish and then continue to execute the function?` Yes

Comment: A thread is a process.